# Como acessar um determinado objeto dentro do JSON através do Axios

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, axios

Quero obter os dados de product_id, product_name e product_price usando o Axios.

```
{
    "status": "success",
    "url": {
        "https://api.exemplo.com/product-1": {
            "data": {
                "product_id": "1",
                "product_name": "bola",
                "product_price": 30
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Seria melhor se você colocasse o código aonde você usa o axios e descreve mais o problema, assim dá para entender melhor a sua dúvida.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No caso, aparentemente, você quer obter os dados contidos no `JSON` dentro do `JavaScript`. Para isso basta desestruturar o objeto:

```js
const resposta = {
  "status": "success",
  "url": {
    "https://api.exemplo.com/product-1": {
      "data": {
        "product_id": "1",
        "product_name": "bola",
        "product_price": 30
      }
    }
  }
}


const { url } = resposta;
const [ [_, conteudo] ] = Object.entries(url);
const {
  data: {
    product_id,
    product_name,
    product_price,
  }
} = conteudo;

console.log(product_id, product_name, product_price);
```